# About calculating Integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to Integrate the following Integral (all of the variables are reals)
$$\int Exp(-(\cos^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{n}_0 (\text{v}_0-\text{x}_0)+\text{n}_1 (\text{v}_1-\text{x}_1)+\text{n}_2 (u \text{v}+\text{v}_2-\text{x}_2)}{\sqrt{\text{n}_0^2+\text{n}_1^2+\text{n}_2^2} \sqrt{(\text{v}_0-\text{x}_0)^2+(\text{v}_1-\text{x}_1)^2+(u \text{v}+\text{v}_2-\text{x}_2)^2}}\right]/m)^2) \, du$$

The formula, simplified, in *Mathematica* input:

```
Integrate[Exp[-(ArcCos[(a + b*u)/(c*Sqrt[d + (e + b*u)^2])]/m)^2], u]
```

If I simply enter that into *Mathematica*, it instantly returns the same expression. If I enter it as an `Integral` with set limits (`0 and t`), it calculates on and on and on....

How do I go about this? Is there any tricks that can be applied to

1. Find out if there is a closed Form for this (obviously including `Erf` terms)
2. Get an Approximation for the Integral (For example using series)
3. Make *Mathematica* take more time trying to find a closed form for the indefinite Integral/antiderivative?

Comment: Actual Mathematica code would be helpful here. Also note that the integration variable shows up only in two places. You can thus simplify the parameters and that might help speed things. For example the numerator of the arccos argument might become a+b*u with a,b assumed to be real.

Comment: Are you sure there is no imaginary unit inside of exponent? Because then it looks more like some integral from optics or something and simplifies to pretty integratable one.

Comment: @swish I am absolutely sure. This is an integral over specular lighting (Gauss Specular lighting) along a part of the z-axis. The formula is $e^{-\angle(H,L)^2}$ - I just realized I forgot the ^2 >_<

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I will try this. However it will make integrating way harder, as there will be a few new variables? That makes simplifying not easier...

Comment: Should be slightly easier as there are fewer new variables than old. Also your `a+b*u` and `e+b*u` appear to be not quite right. I think it should be `n2*(a+b*u)` in the numerator and `a+b*u` in the denominator (`n2` being the constant in the original formulation).

Comment: If you move your origin to $\{v0-x0,v1-x1,v2-x2\}$ so that your $\vec{H}=\{0,0,u v\}$ then it integrates. The integrand would not depend on $u$ at all.

Comment: @swish In fact, I have already made such an optimization to get only the third coordinate of H to change. Originally, $H(u)=\overrightarrow{a}+(\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{a})*u-\overrightarrow{x} + \overrightarrow{v}$. We modified the coordinate system in a way that made $\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{a}={0,0,v}$. If we were to change the coordinate system to make $H(u)={0,0,u*v}$, we would have to inversely transform x,l,n,v in every "step" of integration, which would be almost impossible I fear.

Comment: I will post this to Math.SE in the original form in order to get further assistance. This question is less Mathematica-oriented I fear

Comment: @swish you said it would Integrate... I dont believe so. Mathematica does not find a Integral for $e^{-cos^{-1}(u^2)}$, The resulting function would be way more complicated...

Comment: @CBenni There will be no $u$. The $u$ in a denominator and numerator will cancel each other.

Comment: @swish oic. Too bad this is impossible. I will continue testing and try to find a solution, I will come back to this later.

Comment: @CBenni i think your best bet is to precompute a table of the integral parametrised by the `u`-value of the start- and endpoint of the ray divided by the smallest distance between the surface point and the `u`-parametrised ray (or respectively the start- and end-angle between the points and the connectionline between the surface and the point of minimal distance along the ray). This gives you a 2d-table for the integral, which should have reasonable memory-requirements.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke That is not what I wanted. Of course you can try to approximate the specular highlight by sampling a single point on the ray, but that was not the Intention